# Why is C++23 stacktrace_entry different from source_location?

Tags: c++, stack-trace, c++23

```
class stacktrace_entry {
public:
  string description() const;
  string source_file() const;
  uint_least32_t source_line() const;
  /* ... */
};
```

```
struct source_location {
  // source location field access
  constexpr uint_least32_t line() const noexcept;
  constexpr uint_least32_t column() const noexcept;
  constexpr const char* file_name() const noexcept;
  constexpr const char* function_name() const noexcept;
  /* ... */
};
```

They serve basically the same purpose, why do they have differences, specifically no column in `stacktrace_entry`, or not even share the same class?

Comment: `source_location` is compile-time information of the current location in the source, while `stacktrace_entry` is run-time information of the current call-stack.

Comment: They serve completely *different* purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers from the proposal author.

Regarding returning `std::string`:

> As it is stated in [P0881R7](https://wg21.link/P0881R7): "Unfortunately this is a necessarity on some platforms, where getting source line requires allocating or where source file name [returned into](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/blob/a0f948e9f505cb53baf582fccbcb3024fd255ee1/include/boost/stacktrace/detail/frame_msvc.ipp#L213-L219) a storage [provided by user](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fb%2Fbt_get_backtrace.html)."

Regarding column:

> Most popular solutions for non-Windows platforms do not provide a `source_column()`. At the moment `std::stacktrace` is a minimal subset of abilities of all platforms, so the column is missing. This could be changed later, the addition seems quite simple for C++ standardization.

Answer (score 3):

> They serve basically the same purpose,

They do not serve the same purpose: if anything the entirety of `source_location` offers specific compile-time information which happens to be a small subset of the wider use case of `stacktrace_entry` (particularly it's `source_file` query member function).

---

[P0881R7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0881r7.html) (*A Proposal to add stacktrace library*) introduces the stacktrace library with larger scope or providing details about a call sequence during run-time:

> In the current working draft [N4741] there is no way to get, store and decode the current call sequence. Such call sequences are useful for debugging and post mortem debugging. [...]
>
> This paper proposes classes that could simplify debugging and may change the assertion message into the following: [...]
>
> **Note on performance:** during Boost.Stacktrace development phase many users requested a fast way to store stacktrace, without decoding the function names. This functionality is preserved in the paper. All the stack_frame functions and constructors are lazy and won't decode the pointer information if there was no explicit request from class user.

[P1208R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1208r6.pdf) (*Adopt source_location for C++20*) introduces `source_location` which has more narrow scope, particularly offering certain information about the source code as compile-time information.

The review of P0881 offered some feedback from SG16 on the overlap between the libraries:

> SG16 discussed a number of options including the possibility of `source_file()` returning `std::filesystem::path`. SG16 converged on the following recommendation: "**Align behavior with source_location**; remove wording regarding conversion; string contents are implementation defined. ". No objection to unanimous consent.

However focusing on the `source_file()` query function of the `stacktrace_entry` class as something to align with the entirety of `source_location`. Again placing emphasis on the fact that `stacktrace_entry` serves a much wider purpose that the narrow compile-time information of `source_location` (which, as above, can be viewed as a subset of the `stacktrace_entry` information).

Comment: This clarifies about deliberate distinct classes, but still why doesn't the _wider_ `stacktrace_entry` have the `column`?

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I anything it doesn't belong in `stacktrace_entry` (it's a very minor detail) but rather in `string source_file() const;`. As quoted above " string contents are implementation defined." - it's up to the implementor how far to align the resulting string with the entirety of `source_location`.